# Angular RxJs Observable Avoid Request until i get Previous Response

Tags: javascript, angular, api, rxjs, observable

I have my factory as

```
public InsertUpdateTemp(sysObj): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(this.appSettings.API_Config '/saveEntryTmp', sysObj)
    }
```

This is my call

```
  this.saveservice.InsertUpdateTemp(TempSaveUpdate).subscribe(RtnData => {
          //ok response
     },error => {
          //error response
  })
```

My Factory is working properly saving the data properly

My Problem is 
Suppose in case my server reponse is slow,it will again send request so two entries are saved 
How to avaoid this and do not allow another request until my previous request is completed

How can i achieve this?
**I want to avoid request until i get previous response**

Please let me know if my question is not understandable..

Thanks

Comment: check out concatMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a global variable (for example: `isWaitingResponse` that's false by default).

then in your function:

```
if(!this.isWaitingResponse) {
  this.isWaitingResponse = true;
  this.saveservice.InsertUpdateTemp(TempSaveUpdate).pipe(
    finalize(() => this.isWaitingResponse = false)
  )subscribe(RtnData => {
          //ok response
     },error => {
          //error response
  })
}
```

> **Finalize** could be named **finally** depending on which version of RxJS you
>   are using.

Comment: "rxjs": "^6.0.0",

Comment: Then you need to use finalize. See the changelog here in the deprecation area: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: This is a very good answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

What you want is actually a combination of a service to 'process' your save actions and a way to 'enqueue' these actions one by one to be processed. Below code is RxJs without AngularJs, apply to your own situation as required:

```
// somewhere in constructor of your singleton service
const saveDataSubject = new Subject();
saveDataSubject.pipe(
  concatMap((enqueuedItem) => this.http.post(this.appSettings.API_Config '/saveEntryTmp', enqueuedItem.data).pipe(
    tap(result => enqueuedItem.callback(undefined, result), error => enqueuedItem.callback(error,undefined)),
    catchError(err => empty()),
  )
)
.subscribe();

public InsertUpdateTemp(sysObj): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(sub => {
    saveDataSubject.next({data: sysObj, callback: (err, result) => {
      if(err) {
        return sub.err(err);
      }
      sub.next(result);
      sub.complete();
    }});
  });
});
```

Because the service is a singleton it wires up a stream of changes to persist to the backend (using the Subject). The usage of `concatMap` will make sure changes will be processed one by one. `catchError` is only to prevent an error in the submission of your changes breaking the Observable stream preventing you from processing next values to persist.

There is some magic involved to get the value (or error) from the enqueued action back into the callee of your `InsertUpdateTemp` - this is done using an Observable (so that the actual 'insert' of the data in the queue is lazy untill you subscribe to it) and with a callback invoked by the processing of the stream - which gets translated back to an Observable value emission or error emission as result of your `InsertUpdateTemp()`.